# Integral of $ \frac{\sin8t-3\cos4t}{\sin4t}$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry

Could anyone help me find an antiderivative to

$$ \frac{\sin8t-3\cos4t}{\sin4t}$$

I tried substituting $u = \sin4t$, but that didn't seem to make the integration any easier so perhaps that's the wrong way to go about it. Any suggestions on how to do it?

Comment: Simplify the expression first

Comment: Use the half-angle formula for $\sin(8t)$ and then make the substitution.

Answer (score 2):

Note

$$\int \frac{\sin8t-3\cos4t}{\sin4t}dt$$
$$=\int \left( 2\cos4t - 3\frac {\cos4t}{\sin4t}\right)dt$$
$$=\frac12\int d(\sin4t)- \frac34\int \frac{d(\sin4t)}{\sin4t} $$
$$=\frac12\sin4t -\frac34\ln|\sin4t|+C$$

Comment: Thanks, messed up the simplification but now I see!

Comment: @Nickewas - no problem; you're welcome

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

$$\frac{2\sin4t\cos4t}{\sin4t}-3\frac{\cos 4t}{\sin 4t}=\frac24(\sin 4t)'-\frac34\frac{(\sin 4t)'}{\sin4t}.$$